# Coudln't remove file from View Model: IOException was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, .net-4.0

I was trying to delete an Image from the view Model after some modification but I'm getting this error message `IOException was unhandled`

I disposed the current bitmap `currImgHandler.CurrentBitmap.Dispose();`and also made the Image Source to be null `ViewedPhoto.Source = null;`

if i click on the button which has the Rotate function (90°) once and clikcing on the delete function which produces the error `IOException was unhandled`

If i clcik on the button Roate function `twice`then click on Delete function; I don't get any error and it deletes image without any problem.

What is the mistake am I doing here? Thank you

Selecting an Image from ListView:

```
private string saveFilname;
private void showImage(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
 {

     ListBox list = ((ListBox)sender);
     if (list != null)
     {
         int index = list.SelectedIndex;
         if (index >= 0)
         {
             ImageFileViewModel image = imageListBox.SelectedItem as ImageFileViewModel;

             if ((image != null))
             {
                 saveFilname = image.FileName.ToString();
                 currImgHandler.CurrentFileHandler.Load(image.FileName);
                 PaintImage();

             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Delete Function:

```
private void bDeletePhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   ImageFileCollectionViewModel viewModel = imageListBox.DataContext as ImageFileCollectionViewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        ImageFileViewModel image = imageListBox.SelectedItem as ImageFileViewModel;
        if (image != null)
        {
            //remove physical file from disk:
            currImgHandler.CurrentBitmap.Dispose();
            ViewedPhoto.Source = null; 

            File.Delete(image.FileName);
            //remove item from ObservableCollection:
            viewModel.AllImages.Remove(image);
        }
    }

}
```

//Rotate Function:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//Rotate
{
    currImgHandler.CurrentRotationHandler.Flip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    PaintImage();
}
private void PaintImage()
{
    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    currImgHandler.CurrentBitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    stream.Position = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
    BitmapImage bmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bmapImage.BeginInit();
    bmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bmapImage.EndInit();
    ViewedPhoto.Source = bmapImage; //ImageBox
    ViewedPhoto.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
}
```

Error message:
[image]

Comment: Your error message escaped the message while you weren't looking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `Drew R`suggestion i have added a method in the MVVM itself:

```
public void RemoveOldPhotoItem(ImageFileViewModel imageFile)
        {
            this._allImages.Remove(imageFile);
            this.DataItemsCount++;
            File.Delete(imageFile.FileName);
        }
```

I need to dispose the image which was used by a 3rd party .dll....which  i disposed properly.
Sorry guys it was my mistake. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Your application is throwing an `IOException`. Likely culprit:
`File.Delete(image.FileName);`

IMO You should avoid making calls like this directly in event handlers for the reason demonstrated here - it is hard to catch exceptions thrown directly from an event handler.

If implementing MVVM this doesn't tend to occur.

Comment: If i use the rotate function twice then I can delete. Or I can delete the image file directly before clicking in the 'Rotate' function without any problem.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that your IOException is going unhandled.
If you absolutely have to invoke this code from an event handler, place a `try...catch` block directly around the LoC (`File.Delete(image.FileName)`) and set a breakpoint on the first line of the catch block. This will at least allow you to view the exception detail in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the account privileges under which your application is running are not sufficient to let you delete the file. Please check the credentials of this account against operations on the file you want to delete.

It's only a supposition though, it's hard to be sure without the `IOEXception` content, and it could also be because the path you're using doesn't exist, etc...